# Hololens 2 Unity Bluetooth Gamepad Support

Tags: unity-game-engine, bluetooth, hololens, mrtk, gamepad

So I can't seem to find much information over traditional gamepad support for the Hololens 2 and Unity projects. I've heard that xbox controllers do work but I currently only have a Gamesir T4 Pro and I can't seem to get any input read in my Unity project with the classic and new input systems.

I can connect to the gamepad and it shows up in the Hololens, but it does not seem to provide any input. Does the Hololens not support generic bluetooth controllers?

Comment: Gamesir T4 Pro is designed to work on different platforms and supports multiple compatibility modes. Have you reviewed the product manual to make sure you've put the controller in the correct mode?

Comment: @nondebug I messed around with that and now it's working in the hololens with the browser app so the controller definitely works! My issue now is not getting any input in my app so the issue is on the Unity side of things.